# How to figure out if tableViews footer is displayed?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView and I want to know when the footer will be displayed

Comment: You can observe content offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the scrollView to figure out the end of tableView.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom < height {
            // end of tableView
            
        }
    }
```

and I also used **Bool** to understand when was the first time the footer was displayed

Answer (score -1):

UITableViewDelegate has

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
```

method to get this

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is with the tableView footer and not the section footer.